# No output in Kotlin REPL of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to follow a tutorial where I need to paste Kotlin code into Kotlin REPL of IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

But when I paste the content and press CTRL+ENTER to execute I cannot see any output.

[image]

Any ideas what may cause this issue?

Comment: Type the function name in REPL. In your example it is `main()` and press `Ctrl + Enter` or `Cmd + Enter`

Comment: Omg, makes sense. What a terrible tutorial that is..

Answer (score 0):

You should call you method

Type `main()` then hit `CTRL + ENTER`